# Inconsistent answers between the 'density' and 'spectrum' scaling option of scipy.signal.welch

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, signal-processing, spectrogram

I cannot get consistent answers when using the `scipy.signal.welch` function between the power spectrum density (PSD) 'density' and power spectrum 'spectrum' scaling options in Python 3.

I know that the units for density are V^2/Hz and and for spectrum the units should just be V^2. Therefore, I should be able multiple the PSD by the frequency resolution/bin bandwidth to convert to the power spectrum and vice versa, but I get inconsistent results.  What detail am I missing.